# iOS - How to do drag and drop feature if my sectioned collectionView has a collectionView inside?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview(A) which has a few sections and in this collectionview the cell has a collectionview(B) too.

I want to add a drag and drop feature to my app so that I can re order the cells inside the B collectionview. I also want to be able to move the cells from one B collectionview to another B collectionview.

I've looked at this github tutorial but it doens't help me because of my specific situation.

https://github.com/mmick66/KDDragAndDropCollectionView

So, once again, this is the structure:

```
  - collectionView-A (it has multiple sections)
     - cell:
            - collectionView-B
                - cell:
                       - Label
```

Comment: If you want to use a "pre-built" solution, maybe take a look at this: https://github.com/Oblong/OBDragDrop ... otherwise, there are plenty of examples and tutorials out there - just go through a couple, get a handle on the process, and dive in :)

Comment: Any swift libraries you know instead of obj c?

Comment: You can add that library to your project - doesn't matter that it's written in Obj-C. Otherwise, here is an article (also in Obj-C, but it's a simple conversion to Swift) that can get you going - http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2185202&seqNum=13 ... actual language used is immaterial - the principals are the same.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of **iOS-11**, Apple introduced **Drag and Drop** in `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`.

You can refer to below links for the complete implementation details:

1. **How Drag and Drop works in Collection View**

https://medium.com/@p.gpt10/drag-it-drop-it-in-collection-table-ios-11-6bd28795b313

2. **Sample Project** - It includes drag-drop within 2 collection views as well as reordering.

https://github.com/pgpt10/DragAndDrop-CollectionView

Let me know if you still face any issue with that.